# Homeomorphism Compact Subsets

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness

Are there compact subsets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ with $A$ not homeomorphic to $B$ but $A \times [0,1]$ homeomorphic to $B \times [0,1]$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Consider the two sets below.

[image: The desired sets]

**Edit**: Jon, let me explain in more detail why the two sets (call them $A$ and $B$, respectively) are not homeomorphic. I find in practice that showing two sets to not be homeomorphic is a bit cumbersome. I didn't fill out all of the details for that reason, leaving them to you; let me know if you would like more explanation for anything.

Suppose, seeking a contradiction, that $h:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism.
Let $\alpha:[0,1]\to B$ be a path between
the two points where the crosses intersect the edge of the square
and let $\beta:[0,1]\to B$ be a path between the two points where the sticks intersect the edge. Choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that their images do not intersect, that is, so that $\alpha([0,1])\cap\beta([0,1])=\varnothing$. Now consider the paths $\alpha'=h^{-1}\circ\alpha:[0,1]\to A$ and $\beta'=h^{-1}\circ\beta:[0,1]\to A$. It is still true that $\alpha'$ is a path between the intersections of the crosses and the squares, and that $\beta$ is a path between the intersections of the sticks and the squares (why?). But the images of $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ must intersect (why?), and that is a contradiction.

As for your second question -- why $A'\times[0,1]$ and $B'\times[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic -- let me give you some intuition. The sets $A\times[0,1]$ and $B\times[0,1]$ are homeomorphic because you can move the "branches" across the top of the cube contained in $A\times[0,1]$. But the space $A'\times[0,1]$ is $A\times[0,1]$ with the interior, top, and bottom of the cube removed -- there is no more "top" to move the branches across, and a homeomorphism won't work.

Comment: Why are those sets not homeomorphic?

Comment: @Jin A homeomorphism would preserve the order of cross, line, cross, line around the outside, but the second subset doesn't have that order.

Comment: @sea turtles Why would a homeomorphism preserve the order?

Comment: @Jin It should be intuitively obvious that no amount of warping can change the structure like that without also breaking it. But if you're interested in a sketch of a proof, here's a hint: consider parametrizing the boundary of the square...

Comment: @sea turtles What's different in three dimensions that makes these two homeomorphic?

Comment: In three dimensions you can interchange the "branches" by moving them around, but in two dimensions it is impossible.

Comment: @user134824 Why does this example no longer work if we consider only the boundary of the square? Why are the two new sets obtained in this way now homeomorphic?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I think you're asking about what happens if we replace the solid square in the sets above with the boundary of that square. Call the new sets $A'$ and $B'$. Then $A'$ and $B'$ are not homeomorphic *and* $A'\times[0,1]$ and $B'\times[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @user134824 Let me try to clearly state my doubts as of now: (i) I still don't understand (formally-intuitively I understand) why the two sets you have above are not homeomorphic. If one assumes on the contrary the existence of a homeomorphism, what is the contradiction? The image and inverse image of the solid square would have to be the solid square, but the restriction wouldn't have to be the identity. (ii) Why is $A′\times [0,1]$ not homeomorphic to $B' \times [0,1]$? If you can move the branches around with the solid squares, why can't you do the same thing with the boundaries?

Comment: Can someone address my two doubts?

Comment: Jon, does my edit clear things up?

Comment: @user134824 Thanks, you cleared up my first doubt. As for the second, instead of sliding the branches across the "top" or "bottom," can't one just slide them across the edges that constitute the top and bottom? In this way the branches don't disconnect from the "frame" of the cube.  Is it clear what I am saying? Essentially it doesn't seem to me that the whole top is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addendum to the nice example below.

It was proven by K. Borsuk (Theorem 16 in the paper "[On the decomposition of a locally connected compactum into Cartesian product of a curve and a manifold](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm40115.pdf)", Fund. Math. 40, (1953) 140–159.) that if X, Y are locally connected compacta of dimension at most 1, and their products with interval are homeomorphic then X is homeomorphic to Y. In fact, instead of an interval, one can use any topological manifold with or without boundary.